# Negative dummy variable coefficient for multiple regression analysis

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, dummy-variable

I'm interpreting multiple regression analysis with the endogenous variable being "Forced Labour". I've included the next dummy variables:

- "recruiter relation Friend" - (1=Friend, 0=Not a Friend)
- "rec. rel. Intimate Partner" - (1=Intimate Partner, 0=Not an Intimate Partner"
- "rec. rel. Family" - (1=Family, 0=Not Family)

The output is:

`recruiterRelationFriend           0.069942`

`recruiterRelationIntimatePartner -0.481315`

`recruiterRelationFamily          -0.376550`

Can someone please indicate how how I'd explain one of these? I could guide myself from there thank you!

(I was also wondering if someone could tell me what other models, aside from linear regression, I could use to find more things with dummy-variables. Thanks!)

Comment: I have a number of questions about your model. 1) Is your response normal or is it binary? 2) What is the exact model fit? Have you included/suppressed the intercept? 3) Are there other predictors besides the ones listed?

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand  1) It's a linear model. 2) By model fit you mean the entire summary of the regression? I included the intercept and it is 0.4837 3) There are indeed other predictors, however I separated them into other regressions, I don't know if that's not an okay thing to do

Comment: I know its a linear model, but is the response Gaussian or binomial? By exact fit I meant the regression formula. It is appropriate to separate your predictors into separate regressions if there are strong reasons to do so, but I can't speak to your theory/model-building. It would be best to ask this question on Cross Validated by the way, as this place is more for answering coding questions.